# How can I convert my .spc & .pem file to .pfx file

Tags: openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I have a certificate that is a PKCS#7 certificate (.spc), and also have a .pem file, how can I convert this to .pfx file on OpenSSL app?

Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2):

First, file extensions have no power; they are *usually* used to indicate the format of the file contents but nothing enforces this. Thus a file named 'something.pem' usually *should* contain PEM-format data, but it is entirely possible to use that extension for a file that isn't PEM, and to use a different extension for a file that is PEM.

Second, PEM is not a single format, it is a family of dozens of formats, including about one dozen used for private keys.

If you have a .pem file which is actually a **private key** in one of the PEM formats supported by OpenSSL, and the PKCS7 (.spc) file contains the cert or chain **for the public key which matches** that private key, and you have or get OpenSSL (since you tagged it I assume you do), then:

```
 openssl pkcs7 -in whatever.spc -inform der -print_certs \
 | openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey keyfile.pem -out newfile.pfx
```

If you have a .pem file which is anything other than a PEM-format private key matching the public key in the cert/chain in the PKCS7, you do not have the the data necessary to create a PKCS12/PFX file.

Comment: Thanks for the respond, do i need to open OpenSSL using CMD as Administrator?, and do i need to place my spc and pem file in the directoryof openssl?

Comment: @NicoTing: OpenSSL doesn't need admin on Windows, or root on Unix, or any special privilege besides accessing the files you specify. It can access files anywhere you specify a path and have permission, although _if_ you make your working dir the OpenSSL install dir (you don't need to if you specify the program path or set your PATH envvar) _you_ may find it convenient to put your files there. However, if you install under \Program Files* or \Windows (which is usually not the default) _don't_ put data files there for _any_ program on modern Windows.

Comment: I run CMD as admin and type this:
cd \ |
mkdir certificate |
cd certificate |
set RANDFILE=c:\certificate\.rnd |
set OPENSSL_CONF=c:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\opennssl.cfg |
C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.exe

I put my pem and spc file in the certificate folder, but your code doesnt work

Comment: @NicoTing: I forgot the CMD part. Using backslash to continue a command works on shells but not on CMD. Either type it without the backslash on one logical line (using wraparound) or use 'hat' `^` instead of backslash.